# Working in unity, Variable changed via a function immediately resets to previous value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 Scripts working within unity

Script A (SpawnManager)

Has a Bool called spawnenemy and at the start is set to true.
IENumerator is running to spawn an enemy every couple of seconds.

Script B

Keeps track of score. When score reaches a target score this code runs

```
if (score == targetscore)
{
   _spawnmanager.Stopenemy();
   targetscore += 20;
}
```

Which call this function back in Script A.

```
public void Stopenemy()
{
   SpawnEnemy = false;
}
```

Script A then stops spawning enemys.  And a Boss appears. (Upto this point everything works as it should)

Scripts C tracks the boss.
When boss is defeated Script C runs

```
public void reactor()
{
   reactordestroyed++;

   if (reactordestroyed == 3)
   {
      reactordestroyed = 0;
      SpawnManager.Startenemy(true);
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
   }
}
```

Which calls this function in Script A

```
public void Startenemy(bool gonad)
{
   SpawnEnemy = gonad;
}
```

However SpawnEnemy gets updated within the function and becomes true, but instantly resets back to false.
I have Debug.Log on both Void Update and void Startenemy and can confirm the debug in startenemy shows Spawnenemy to be true but the void update never shows it to be true only false.
What is supposed to happen is the Spwanenemy changes back to true to allow the IEnumerator to cycle another wave of enemies.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to reformat this question again, use the code markdown for code, also I'm not sure why you have so many <BR> tags in the post.

Comment: The breaks were to space the question out so it was easier to follow.  I didnt like everything being truncated.

Comment: are you transitioning to different scenes?

Comment: No transition to different scenes.

Comment: Your code looks completely fine to me. The error must be on other places of the scripts. For instance, you have `SpawnManager` and `_spawnmanager` on two different scripts referring the same script. Are you sure they are pointing to the same script?

Comment: Yeah, it was just a different name in each script but both still pointed to the right script.  Like I said using debug.log in the function of the Target script.  The information was being passed correctly, just not applying the change permanently.  I think its a Unity3D bug associated with the IENumerator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be constantly calling `Stopenemy();`
Try changing

```
if (score == targetscore)
{
    _spawnmanager.Stopenemy();
    targetscore += 20;
}
```

to

```
if (score ==targetscore&&bossNotSpawned)
{
    _spawnmanager.Stopenemy();
    targetscore += 20;
}
```

Comment: Stopenemy is only called once as targetscore is changed to a value that does not equal score.  The if statement will only run if score = target score.  Debug.Log confirms that the target score does not equal score after targetscore is increased.

Comment: Another Debug.Log within public void Stopenemy() confirms this function is only called once.